# Cannot boot Kubuntu after CD install

Tags: boot

I have installed Kubuntu 11.04 and had to install it several times before it would boot up after the CD install. I would get the message that no operating system found. I upgraded to 11.xx and it worked fine. I then wanted to put 12.04 on the HP desktop and it will not boot either after several installs. I went back to try to install the 11.04 as it worked before but now it does not boot either. I need help with this process. Anyone out there have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a live CD, mount the hard drive, then check the logs in `/mount_path/var/log`.